# How to make a notepad based on liked-list?

Tags: java, user-interface, data-structures

I am familiar with data-structures in java. Linked-list seems to be the right choice for the notepad basis but I don't know how to implement it.

I need directions in terms of how can I realize all the functions of a notepad via Linked-list(or do I need anything extra) and then some guidance in the GUI.

I know programming and data-structures just fine. I have never done GUI. I want to develop complex GUI software but don't know the right resources. After a lot of thinking I thought I should begin with an interactive notepad.

Comment: This question is very unspecific and too broad to answer. Furthermore *I want to use LinkedList for a notepad editor* is also very unspecific and therefore it is not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: A notepad needs be based on some data-structure. I think Linked-List can do the task.

Comment: Use `javax.swing`. It is the built in library for Java GUI

Comment: @Aderis or AWT. Or JavaFX. Just to name two more, which come with the java STL. This is another reason the question should be closed. Parts are opinion-based.

Comment: @user4275686 datastructure for what? If you code this kind of GUI, you will need more than one datastructure, e.g. some kind of stack for the [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern). If you are talking about the datastructure used for the acutal text, I would not use a `LinkedList`, but a `StringBuilder` in a first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

For java GUI, please try to search some materials and tutorials of java swing by google. Learn some swing knowledge is good, however, I don't suggest u pay too much time in this. Because java GUI is seldomly used in project works. In current client GUI projects, C# is a much better option than java. In B/S architect projects, javascript and HTML is mostly used to implement GUI in browser.